# How to Get DynamoDB particular table data change and send silent push to all users to receive data from that table in AWS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am working on iOS app and used swift version.

i have used DynamoDB table to store category data. If admin add/delete/update data in DynamoDB then i want to send silent push to all app users so i will fetch category table data and update.

Is there any other way to get that anything changed in table and update in all app?

Thanks in advance!